# Menu with links floated at left and right but aligned at center in terms of height

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Im trying to have a menu where I have some links floated at left and then I have a `div` with some links that I want floated at right.

I'm trying to do this with the code below and it is working, but the left links and right links are no aligned at the center of the menu in terms of `height`, do you know why?

And also the `:hover` effect is not occupying the entire `height` of the menu.

CODE:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
.content {
  height: 50px;
}
.menu-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu-list li {
  float: left;
}
.menu-links {
  float: right;
}
.menu-list li a {
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.menu-list li a:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="menu-links">
      <a href="">Link 1</a> 
      <a href="">Link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9vLLkh7/1/)

Comment: I reccomend flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```css
.container{
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
}

.content{
      height: 50px;
}

.menu-list{
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0;
    float: left;
}

.menu-list li{
   display: inline-block;
}

.menu-links{
    float: right;

}
.menu-links a{
    line-height: 50px;
}

.menu-list li a{
    color:#aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;


}

.menu-list li a:hover{
    background:red;
    padding: 16px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
    </ul> 
    <div class="menu-links">
      <a href="">Link 1</a> 
      <a href="" >Link 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/7dLh96ja/)

It happens because, you have used **menu-list with ul** and **menu-links with div**.

In basic HTML, **ul has predefined padding and margin.** So, first of all clear out that padding and margin then style **menu-list and menu-links** accordingly.

Instead of adding extra space or element use following html,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="menu-list">
            <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a title="" href="">Home</a></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="menu-links">
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your respective CSS will be,

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

.container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
}

.container:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

a {
   text-decoration: none
}

.menu-list,
.menu-links {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0
}

.menu-list {
    float: left
}

.menu-links {
   float: right
}

.menu-list li,
.menu-links li {
    display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Revised to make CSS only

Would something like this work? You just need to know the height of your nav bar, and add a pseudo-element of that height to each of the separate nav sections. https://jsfiddle.net/will0220/wg7hwc7s/

Just set them to display: inline-block and vertical-align: middle to keep them centered in the height of your nav bar by comparing it to the pseudo element. This should work with any number of lines of text in each button.

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
}
.menu-list{
  list-style:none;
}
.menu-list{
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu-links{
    float: right;
}
.menu-list li a{
    color:#aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu-list:before, .menu-links:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  width: 0;
}
.menu-list li, .menu-links a{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu-list li a:hover{
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Le5nbfdw/)?

It is generally better to float the `ul` and give the `li` `display: inline;`

`ul` also has a default margin and padding on it so you need to use a reset of some sort

```
ul.menu-list{
  margin: 0 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table-cell` property to easily do that and also you don't have to use float for **li** to display as horizontal menu instead use `display:inline`

updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w9vLLkh7/2/)